# URL rewriting with other actions

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting

I've currently got a PHP web application that accepts URLs as: /page.3, and the index file get the number, and uses it:

```
/page.3 > $_GET['id'] = 3
```

IIS URL Rewrite Pattern is:

```
^([^/]+/)*([^/]+/)\.(\d+)$
```

and it produces `index.php?id={R:3}`

However, I want to be able to specify other parameters, e.g.

```
/page.3&do=4 > $_GET['id'] = 3 and $_GET['do'] = 4
```

Is there any way I can do this using IIS Rewriting or PHP?

Comment: If your rewrite rule includes the query string in the final url you may just use /page.3?do=4 and get do from $_GET as well ...

Comment: I've tried that, but I'll have a go again

Comment: Don't know IIS, but in apache there is a setting for rewritting that says apache to append query string after rewritting/redirecting - [QSA]. According to @yent and maybe right setting of IIS You should be able to call Your page in the manner @yent shows: /page.3?do=4 or maybe /page.3/?do=4

Comment: Well, if I can get the Apache rewrite, then I can convert it to IIS :)

Comment: Is this the IIS7 UrlRewriter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I can't get your regular expression to match anything like `/page.3` in a url so I came up with my own:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RWW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="((.+)\.(\d+))" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?id={R:3}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

By default the rewriter will append your query string.